# Parallel.ForEach loop with BlockingCollection.GetConsumableEnumerable

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach, blockingcollection

Why `Parallel.ForEach` loop exits with `OperationCancelledException`, while using `GetConsumableEnumerable`?

```
//outside the function
static BlockingCollection<double> _collection = new BlockingCollection<double>();
    
    
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Producer);            
Parallel.ForEach(_collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
    item => Console.WriteLine("Processed {0}", item));
Console.WriteLine("FINISHED processing");


public static void Producer()
{
     var data = Enumerable.Range(1, 1000);
     foreach (var i in data)
     {
        _collection.Add(i);
        Console.WriteLine("Added {0}",i);
     }
                    
     Console.WriteLine("Finished adding");
     _collection.CompleteAdding();
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the `OperationCancelledException` behavior on .NET 7. The code in the question runs successfully to completion, no exception is thrown.

Answer (score 26):

Using `Parallel.ForEach` with `BlockingCollection` is somewhat problematic, as I found out recently. It can be made to work, but it needs a little extra effort.

Stephen Toub has an [excellent blog post on it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/), and if you download the ["Parallel Extension Extras"](https://github.com/afedyanin/parallel) project ([also available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/)) you'll find some code ready to help you.

Comment: What really puzzles me is why Parallel.ForEach throws exception when I call _collection.CompleteAdding().

Comment: @Sam: I wouldn't like to say, to be honest. There's too much deep magic going on there for me to have any confidence in saying the right thing :)

Comment: The current URL to the Parallel Extensions Extras:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples
and someone has made a NuGet of the extensions:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSFT.ParallelExtensionsExtras/

Comment: A more recent article on this combination by Can Bilgin - [link](https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2017/02/05/curious-case-of-parallel-foreach-with-blockingcollection/)

Comment: link to blog: [ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour – #4 – BlockingCollectionExtensions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallelextensionsextras-tour-4-blockingcollectionextensions/)

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) with a [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) as source, requires two specific adjustments:

1. Use the [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) option.
2. Specify the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) to a value other than `-1`.

Example of correct usage:

```
Partitioner<Item> partitioner = Partitioner.Create(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
    EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

ParallelOptions options = new()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount
};

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, item =>
{
    //...
});
```

Explanation:

1. The [`EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.enumerablepartitioneroptions) is required because otherwise the `Parallel.ForEach` will not process immediately each consumed item. Instead it will put the item in a small buffer, and will wait until the buffer reaches an arbitrary size before processing all the items in the buffer. This behavior introduces undesirable latency, and can even cause deadlocks in some advanced scenarios.
2. Configuring the [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) is required in order to keep the [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) usage under control. Otherwise the `Parallel.ForEach` will keep asking for more and more threads, prompting the `ThreadPool` to create new threads at a rate of one new thread per second, even while the `BlockingCollection<T>` is completely empty and the parallel loop is idle! For an experimental demonstration of this strange behavior, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75418588/parallel-foreach-on-a-blockingcollection-causes-steady-increase-of-threads).