# PLINQ inside task sometime slower

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I'm working on some text parser logic and have IO and CPU bound operations.
In general what I do: read file -> process text, read file 2 -> process text 2... and so on.

What I can do is to make operations "process text" and "read file 2" executing at the same time in different tasks. However when I created tree of related tasks I noticed that PLINQ became slower than it was initially. Here is simplified example of code:

class Program
{
    static int idx;

```
public static void Main()
{
    idx = 0;
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        // here I execute my function with PLINQ
        FuncP();
    }

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

    idx = 0;

    sw.Start();

    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int iLocal = i;
        Task tsk;
        if (i > 0)
        {
            // next task depends on previous one
            tsk = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks[iLocal - 1]);

                // execute the same function
                FuncP();
            });
        }
        else // i = 0
        {
            // first task does not depend on other tasks
            tsk = Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    // execute the same function
                    FuncP();
                });
        }

        tasks.Add(tsk);
    }

    tasks.Last().Wait();
    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

private static void FuncP()
{
    Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
    sw1.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FuncP start {0}", ++idx));
    string s = new string('c', 2000);
    s.AsParallel()
        .ForAll(_ =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) ;
        });

    sw1.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FuncP end {0}, Elapsed {1}", idx, sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds));
}
```

}

Output is:

```
FuncP start 1
FuncP end 1, Elapsed 409
FuncP start 2
FuncP end 2, Elapsed 345
FuncP start 3
FuncP end 3, Elapsed 344
FuncP start 4
FuncP end 4, Elapsed 337
FuncP start 5
FuncP end 5, Elapsed 344
FuncP start 6
FuncP end 6, Elapsed 343
FuncP start 7
FuncP end 7, Elapsed 348
FuncP start 8
FuncP end 8, Elapsed 351
FuncP start 9
FuncP end 9, Elapsed 343
FuncP start 10
FuncP end 10, Elapsed 334
3504
FuncP start 1
FuncP end 1, Elapsed 5522 --> here is high execution time
FuncP start 2
FuncP end 2, Elapsed 368
FuncP start 3
FuncP end 3, Elapsed 340
FuncP start 4
FuncP end 4, Elapsed 347
FuncP start 5
FuncP end 5, Elapsed 351
FuncP start 6
FuncP end 6, Elapsed 347
FuncP start 7
FuncP end 7, Elapsed 353
FuncP start 8
FuncP end 8, Elapsed 337
FuncP start 9
FuncP end 9, Elapsed 341
FuncP start 10
FuncP end 10, Elapsed 345
12160
```

Sometimes it hangs on first run PLINQ in task, sometimes on second one, but with tasks it takes much more time that in loop.
Not sure I understand exactly the reason why `FuncP` execution time is so high, could it be that `AsParallel()` does not make it parellel due to lack of "free" threads in thread pool?
Can someone explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole approach seems problematic (e.g. the use of `Task.WaitAll(tasks[iLocal - 1]);` is not thread-safe since a different thread may be adding to `tasks` at the same time). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library may be worth considering as an alternative. Or if you don't want to learn that, have `read file` add to a `BlockingCollection` which `process text` reads from in a different thread / task. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608042/parallel-foreach-loop-with-blockingcollection-getconsumableenumerable .

Comment: @mjwills sure,I understand all this, just example of roughly made code, was interested mainly in reason for timings, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is likely caused by the fact that the Thread Pool is reasonably [conservative](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff963549.aspx) *(search the article for `Thread Injection`)* in how many spare threads it has lying around. *Matt Warren's [article](http://mattwarren.org/2017/04/13/The-CLR-Thread-Pool-Thread-Injection-Algorithm/) is worth a read on the issue.*

If you set the ThreadPool to have a **minimum** number of threads, for example using:

```
ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
```

then the two code samples act roughly the same since 'spare' threads are available.

*Note that I would not suggest using 100 in production - it is merely an example to show the contrast.*