# Parallel.ForEach on a BlockingCollection causes steady increase of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, threadpool, parallel.foreach, blockingcollection

I observed a strange behavior while experimenting with the [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach) method and the [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class. Apparently calling the two lines below on a separate thread, is enough to cause an ever increasing number of threads in the `ThreadPool`:

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), _ => { });
```

The `queue` contains no elements. I was expecting that the `Parallel.ForEach` loop would be idle, waiting for items to be added in the `queue`. Apparently it's not idle, because the [`ThreadPool.ThreadCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.threadcount) is increasing by one every second. Here is a minimal demo:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            var queue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
            Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), _ => { });
        })
        { IsBackground = true }.Start();

        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ThreadCount: {ThreadPool.ThreadCount}");
            if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > 8000) break;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ThreadCount: 0
ThreadCount: 4
ThreadCount: 5
ThreadCount: 6
ThreadCount: 7
ThreadCount: 8
ThreadCount: 10
ThreadCount: 11
ThreadCount: 12
Finished
```

[Online demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/H6MWxb).

Can anyone explain why is this happening, and how to prevent it from happening? Ideally I would like the `Parallel.ForEach` to consume at most one `ThreadPool` thread, while the `queue` is empty.

I am searching for a solution applicable on .NET Core 3.1 and later.

Comment: Not really sure. But could it be that `Parallel.Foreach` spawns a new thread for each time the thread is scheduled on which it has been created? That would explain the observed behavior to me. But why it would do that? For this we would have to deep dive into its implementation, I guess.

Comment: On first glance, for a solution, I would say "don't do that", seems to be a bad combo. I would guess a dataflow solution would do a better job, perhaps.

Comment: @Fildor actually I used this combination yesterday, in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099703/parallel-tree-traversal-in-c-sharp/75414185#75414185 "Parallel tree traversal in C#") answer, for solving the problem of parallel hierarchical traversal. I was thinking that it was a good quality solution, until I discovered this issue. That answer is susceptible to the problem presented here. In case the `root` takes a lot of time to be processed, the `Parallel.ForEach` will be spawning threads every second during this time...

Comment: It's surprising, to say the least, yes. I personally wouldn't use it after having found what you have found. I just don't know if this is a bug or "works as designed".

Comment: @Fildor probably it works as designed. As shown in [Shingo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75419257/11178549) answer, if I don't specify the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` it's like asking the `Parallel.ForEach` to saturate my `ThreadPool`...

Comment: That's what I thought. And it kind of makes sense. But for this use case it's a bit unfortunate. I personally am not a fan of "unlimited" deg of concurrency, anyway but well... I am not everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason**

The *Parallel.ForEach* method partitions the enumerable first, then it uses [TaskReplicator.Run](https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,2866) to run the action on each partition.

The actual runner is the method [Replica.Execute](https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskReplicator.cs,69). In the beginning of the method, because the enumerable is blocked, the replica won't stop, it will create its replica until _*remainingConcurrency* is 0.

The _*remainingConcurrency* field is initialed from the [ParallelOptions.EffectiveMaxConcurrencyLevel](https://source.dot.net/#System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel/System/Threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs,107) option, its default value is -1, which means unlimited. So you saw the *ThreadCount* kept increasing.

**Solution**

Because we know the reason, we just need to specific a reasonable option to limit the iteration count.

```
var option = new ParallelOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
};
Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingEnumerable(), option, _ => { });
```

Comment: Thanks Shingo for the answer. Yes, I thought about specifying the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` to reduce the damage, but I was hoping for a solution that would minimize the `ThreadPool` usage down to one thread. In case a perfect solution is not found, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: That is about what I have been suspecting. As Theodor said, I would consider setting a max rather a "patch" than a solution. It avoids the worst case of the behavior but it is not _exactly_ what he wants. But I guess that's as good as you can get with that combination if you want to stick to it.

Comment: I think you can just use a synchronous foreach for the blockingcollection and create a task for each iteration, according to the code, there is no much difference unless the collection contains a mass of data.